# Indexes differences between MSSQL and MariaDB

Tags: sql-server, mariadb, unique-key, unique-index

I am porting a MSSQL database to MariaDB, I have a complete SQL dump produced by HeidiSQL.  The MSSQL database has several indexes declared as:

```
    UNIQUE KEY ("JobCodeId","Rate")
```

Which I assume is the same as:

```
    UNIQUE INDEX (`JobCodeId`,`Rate`)
```

However, in the same SQL there are lots of inserts with the same values for JobCodeId and Rate, which when I don't understand, I would expect the above to mean that there cannot be any two records sharing the same JobCodeId and Rate, but in the MSSQL tables there are....MariaDB will not allow it and I understand why, so what is the difference?

This is the MSSQL table definition:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Activity" (
"ActivityId" BIGINT(19,0) NOT NULL,
"JobCodeId" BIGINT(19,0) NOT NULL,
"ActivityDetailId" SMALLINT(5,0) NOT NULL,
"Rate" SMALLMONEY(10,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
"CreationDateTime" DATETIME(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
"DisabledDateTime" DATETIME(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY ("ActivityDetailId"),
PRIMARY KEY ("ActivityId"),
UNIQUE KEY ("JobCodeId","Rate")
```

);

And here is the just the first few inserts:

```
    INSERT INTO "Activity" ("ActivityId", "JobCodeId", "ActivityDetailId", "Rate", "CreationDateTime", "DisabledDateTime") VALUES
(19, 31, 8, 35, '2011-09-15 10:54:02.630', NULL),
(20, 31, 10, 42, '2011-09-15 10:54:35.907', NULL),
(21, 31, 11, 42, '2011-09-15 10:54:55.580', NULL);
```

The modified SQL for MariaDB looks like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Activity" (
"ActivityId" BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
"JobCodeId" BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
"ActivityDetailId" SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL,
"Rate" NUMERIC(15,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
"CreationDateTime" DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
"DisabledDateTime" DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
UNIQUE INDEX ("ActivityDetailId"),
PRIMARY KEY ("ActivityId"),
UNIQUE INDEX ("JobCodeId","Rate")
```

);

When I try to action the inserts MariaDB throws an error, which is what I would expect given the definition, but why and how does it work in MSSQL?

Comment: The only thing that occurs to me is that [the index/constraint has been disabled in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177456(v=sql.120).aspx).

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` that you've shown is not MS SQL Server syntax. MS SQL Server doesn't have the types that you've shown, such as `DATETIME(3)`. There is something strange there. It is possible that the tool that you use to dump the table definition tries to convert SQL Server syntax into MySQL syntax and doesn't do everything correctly. Show us the true definition of the table from SQL Server. Use SQL Server Management Studio to obtain that definition - right-click on the table and Script Table As Create.

Comment: I used HeidiSQL on the clients server and I'm pretty sure the server is running MSSQL.

Comment: What is the complete error message?